# Symfony: check user authorization inside event listener

Tags: symfony

I'm new to Symfony (Currently using Symfony 3.2) and I'm learning how to create event listener for run my random functions before every controllers. My goal is to check by isGranted() function that user is logged or not. Take a look at my code

### services.yml

```
> parameters:
> #    parameter_name: value
> 
> services:
>     app.form_login_authenticator:
>         class: AppBundle\Security\FormLoginAuthenticator
>         arguments: ["@router", "@security.password_encoder"]
>     app.init.action_listener:
>         class: AppBundle\EventListener\InitListener
>         tags:
>             - { name: kernel.event_listener, event: kernel.controller, method: onKernelController }
```

### InitListener

```
> <?php namespace AppBundle\EventListener;
> 
> use AppBundle\Controller\InitController; use
> Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\Exception\AccessDeniedHttpException; use
> Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\Event\FilterControllerEvent; use
> Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Session\Session; 
>
>  class InitListener {
>     
>     public function onKernelController(FilterControllerEvent $event)
>     {
>         $controller = $event->getController(); 
> 
>        
> 
>         //if ($this->get('security.authorization_checker')->isGranted('IS_AUTHENTICATED_FULLY'))
>         //{
>         // do somehting
>         //}else{
>         // do somehting
>         //}
>         if ($controller[0] instanceof InitController) {
>           
>         }
>         if (!is_array($controller)) {
>             return;
>         }
>    
>    
>     }
>  }
```

What should I do to use isGranted() function inside my InitListener?

Comment: Why not just setup `access_control` patterns in your security.yml? That way you can just be sure the user is logged in (and has certain roles, if you like so) when your controller gets executed.

Comment: Yes but for example based on whether user is logged in or not I'm creating avatar paths in session.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Obviously you should pass `security.authorization_checker` into your listener.

First in config

```
 app.init.action_listener:
     class: AppBundle\EventListener\InitListener
     arguments: ["@security.authorization_checker"]
     tags:
         - { name: kernel.event_listener, event: kernel.controller, method: onKernelController }
```

and then in the code

```
 <?php namespace AppBundle\EventListener;

 use AppBundle\Controller\InitController; 
 use Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\Exception\AccessDeniedHttpException; 
 use Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\Event\FilterControllerEvent; 
 use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Session\Session; 
 use Symfony\Component\Security\Core\Authorization\AuthorizationCheckerInterface

 class InitListener {

     protected $authorizationChecker;

     public function __construct(AuthorizationCheckerInterface $authorizationChecker)
     {
         $this->authorizationChecker = $authorizationChecker;
     }

     public function onKernelController(FilterControllerEvent $event)
     {
         $controller = $event->getController(); 

         if ($this->authorizationChecker->isGranted('IS_AUTHENTICATED_FULLY')) {
             // DO YOUR STUFF
         }       

         if ($controller[0] instanceof InitController) {

         }
         if (!is_array($controller)) {
             return;
         }


     }
  }
```

Comment: You, aswell as OP, should switch the `is_array` up before accessing `$controller[0]`.

Comment: No, this will not work as you will have problems with isGranted() when the user is not logged in and no token exists.